# Searching through tables for a value

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedure, plsql

I have a PL/SQL stored procedure which searches for a row in 3 different tables (not all columns are the same).

The logic goes as follows:

> ```
> Search for the item in the first table
>   If item was found
>       select the details of it from the first table
>   If item was not found
>       search for the item in the second table
>           If Item was found
>               Select the details of it from the second table
>           If item was not found
>               Select the item from the third table (returning blank if it's not found here neither)
> ```

Here's the actual code (actual symbol names modified for security):

```sql
PROCEDURE GETREQUEST(REQUESTID IN NUMBER, request OUT pkg_request.refcur)
 IS
requestFound NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN

            -- Search for the request ID in the first table
            SELECT COUNT(REQ_ID) INTO requestFound FROM FIRSTTABLE
            WHERE FIRSTTABLE.REQ_ID = REQUESTID
            AND (REQ_STATUS = 'D' OR REQ_STATUS = 'A');

            IF(REQUESTFOUND > 0) THEN
                    -- Select the request details
                    OPEN REQUEST FOR
                    SELECT REQ_ID, REQ_TYPE_STATUS FROM FIRSTTABLE
                    WHERE FIRSTTABLE.REQ_ID = REQUESTID
                    AND (REQ_STATUS = 'D' OR REQ_STATUS = 'A');
            ELSE
                    -- Search for the request from the second table
                    SELECT COUNT(REQ_ID) INTO REQUESTFOUND FROM SECONDTABLE
                    WHERE SECONDTABLE.REQ_ID = REQUESTID;

                    IF(REQUESTFOUND > 0) THEN
                              -- Select the request details from second table
                              OPEN REQUEST FOR
                              SELECT REQ_TYPE, '-' AS REQ_TYPE_STATUS FROM SECONDTABLE
                              WHERE SECONDTABLE.REQ_ID = REQUESTID;
                      ELSE
                              -- Get the request from third table (will return as blank if nothing found)
                              OPEN REQUEST FOR
                              SELECT REQ_TYPE, '-' AS REQ_TYPE_STATUS  FROM THIRDTABLE
                              WHERE THIRDTABLE.REQ_ID = REQUESTID;
                      END IF;
            END IF;
END GET_REQUEST
```

My issues with this are as follows:

- It's not very concise, with a lot of nesting.
- It's not very efficient, since it needs to perform a count, then if it exists it selects the details. That's two operations. How can I modify it to have a single operation for each search?

Also, the `REQ_TYPE_STATUS` column doesn't exist in the second and third table, so as you can see I have just assigned the value '-' to the returned result, indicating a blank value. I'm not really sure if there's a better or more standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you current solution is a prime example of inappropriate use of PL/SQL when plain SQL provides much more elegant solution:

```
create table t1 (
  id number,
  status varchar2(10)
);

create table t2 (
  id number
);

create table t3 (
  id number
);

insert into t1 values(1,'A');
insert into t2 values(2);
insert into t3 values(3);
insert into t1 values(4,'A');
insert into t2 values(4);
insert into t3 values(4);

select source, priority, id, status from (
  select 't1' as source, 1 as priority, id, status from t1 where status in ('A', 'D')
  union
  select 't2' as source, 2, id, null from t2
  union
  select 't3' as source, 3, id, null from t3
)
where id = 1
order by priority
;
```

The `source` is just for demonstration and `priority` is to guarantee the correct ordering of the tables. The `priority` is not needed if you have other rules ensuring the id is found only from one table. If the id can be found from different tables just add a wrapper `rownum = 1`-query (the details left for exercise) to pick the first one only. Now just wrap that inside your PL/SQL as you see appropriate.

When some information is not available in all tables it's up to you what is the value indicating missing value. It can be e.g. `null` or `-` or `-1` depending on the context. However I'd recommend `null` unless there is other factors that rule that out.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Brilliant work, this is a much shorter and simpler solution!

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure there is a way to reduce the number of if-statements and nesting. What is possible though is to improve the performance of the conditions you have that check those conditions.

The count(*) is inefficient. Consider adding a 'ROWNUM = 1' condition to your where clause in a way that makes the following conditions possible:

```
        SELECT COUNT(REQ_ID) INTO requestFound
        FROM FIRSTTABLE
        WHERE FIRSTTABLE.REQ_ID = REQUESTID
          AND (REQ_STATUS = 'D' OR REQ_STATUS = 'A')
          AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

This will be optimized by Oracle to exit the condition on the first matching result, ending up with a `requestFound` value that will be either 0, or 1. A value of 1 means there is some data, and does not indicate how much data.

[Reading up on ROWNUM is useful. Ask Tom!](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html)